# Unexpected behavior from prompt js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn javascript, and as part of that exercise, I decided to attempt to create a blackjack simulator to increase my accumen and skills.

Below is an isolated block from the program. I'm using prompt instead of an html interface for simplicity.

```
function askAboutAce(){
    var nResponse = 0;
    var response = 0;
    response = prompt("Would you like to use the ace as a 1 or 11?");
    if(response === "1" || response === "11"){
        nResponse = Number(response);
        return nResponse;
    }
    else{
        askAboutAce();
    }
}

var x = 2 + askAboutAce();
console.log(x);
```

The line `var x = 2 + askAboutAce();` is simulating the player first drawing a 2, and then drawing an Ace. The odd behavior occurs when I execute the following: If the prompt asks for what I'd like to do with the ace, and I respond correctly (that is, with a 1 or an 11) then the return value is a number. However, if I respond incorrectly (by entering any other number besides 1 or 11) and then eventually I enter the 1 or 11, the return value is NaN. I find that behavior very odd and hypothesize that it has something to do with the resolution of the stack of actions caused by the use of recursion. Please help me understand the unexpected behavior.

Comment: prompt returns a String. pressing cancel returns null. you can use ` nResponse = Number(response) || 0;` to make sure you have a number to do math (especially addition) upon.

Comment: try response = parseInt(prompt())  and check the condition without quotes

Comment: In the above scenario, I never pressed cancel. I also compensate for the String with the line `nResponse = Number(response);`

Comment: I guess, what I'm asking, is why the odd behavior from NOT entering it correctly the first time. That's what I want to understand.

Comment: You need to use 'return askAboutAce();' in the else part. Otherwise undefined will be the return value

Comment: Also @blessnm that worked. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every function in javascipt has a return value. If you dont specify anything it will be `undefined` by default. In the 'if' condition u return the number which is correct. But in the 'else' condition u call the function again which may return a number but since you are not returning the result of the function call, the engine will just return `undefined` instead. `Number(undefined)` is `NaN`. Using the '+' operator with `undefined` will try to coerce it into a number. There are more rules regarding implicit coercion.

Use `return askAboutAce();` in the else condition.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a personal preference but recursion is not really necessary here. I think a simpler and perhaps easier to follow way for your `askAboutAce` function is this

```
function askAboutAce(){
    var response;
    do {
        response = prompt("Would you like to use the ace as a 1 or 11?");
    } while (response !== "1" && response !== "11")

    return Number(response);

}

var x = 2 + askAboutAce();
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your code in this block...

```
if(response === "1" || response === "11"){
    nResponse = Number(response);
    return nResponse;
}
else{
    askAboutAce();
}
```

nothing is being returned for the else statement.
The value from askAboutAce() is just being returned to... nowhere.

So you would need to return the output from that method.

EX:

```
else{
    return askAboutAce();
}
```